optimization help griddb
I'm using GridDB to manage a large dataset that includes time-series data. While the system generally performs well, I've noticed that certain queries, especially those involving range scans or complex conditions, take longer than expected to execute.
My setup:
GridDB, Cluster size: 3 nodes, TimeSeries containers with a large number of rows (millions per container)
Query example:
SELECT * FROM myTimeSeries WHERE timestamp > TIMESTAMP('2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z') AND sensor_value > 50;

What I've tried:

Ensured that the cluster is balanced across nodes.

Verified that the time-series data is being partitioned correctly.

Experimented with different query structures, but the performance gains were minimal.
Question:


What are the best practices for optimizing query performance in GridDB, particularly for large datasets and time-series data? Are there specific configurations, indexing strategies, or query patterns that can help speed up query execution?
reference: https://docs.griddb.net

What kind of indexes do you have on myTimeSeries?

i haven't added any to that field yet

...there be your problem friend.

Thanks! that worked
